# Нужно поудалять абсурдные метки

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Я заметил, что в списке меток (особенно среди новых) на сайте есть несколько таких, которые имеют совершенно абсурдный смысл. К примеру, [повторятьприпечатистроки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8) или [интерналионализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f). Думаю, при желании, можно нарыть и ещё немало. Вряд ли эти метки понадобятся кому-нибудь еще, так может их удалить?